# What does this function's signature mean?

Tags: angular, function, typescript, types

I am following this [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2), which has a [live example](https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview) and it defines this function:

```
onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
  this.selectedHero = hero;
}
```

where `: void` is the part I don't understand. How is this part called, and what does it do?

---

My idea: It's the return type of the function, but if that was the case, shouldn't

```
onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
  this.selectedHero = hero;
  return hero;
}
```

throw an error? The app is working fine in Plunker and no error is shown in the console (I wonder though whether this has to do with Plunker somehow).

The function is called like this:

```
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
    (click)="onSelect(hero)">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
```

Comment: onSelect(hero: Hero): Hero

Comment: Prototype? Your whole question body doesn't mention a prototype. I'll guess you meant *signature*.

Comment: @gsamaras Ratio is about normal I'd say. Maybe increased traffic from people who wondered about "prototype" but then found it not interesting at all, like myself :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea is correct. It's simply a return type just like functions in other programming languages like C#. And the case when you are returning object of type Hero, it should give an error like this `Type 'Hero' is not assignable to type 'void'`, as shown in the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It means that your function doesn't return anything and you can't call like this

```
let result = this.onSelect(someHero); // Here compiler will give you an error that the function can't be in the right side of the statement
```

See an example [**here**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20public%20onSelect(hero%3A%20string)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20return%20hero%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A). Probably it is the error of Plunker, because in their web site you can see the error.

Answer (score 1):

function is not returning anything `[void]`

```
onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
  this.selectedHero = hero;
}
```

This method when invoked just initialises the class level `selectedHero` with the hero passed to the method. If you see the typescript class you will find a `selectedHero:Hero` variable in the component.

Comment: Yeah I knew that about the class. Thanks for the answer, +1. however I didn't accept yours because you didn't explain why my idea failed.